# Excel VBA - Copying data based on two parameters into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I'm trying to copy data from one sheet that contains raw data (over 30 columns and 300000 rows) into other sheets that split them into organized form.

In the DATA sheet I have repetitive ID's in column A, case numbers in column B which are unique and dates of cases in column J (multiple case numbers have the same date).

My goal is to copy case numbers into worksheets that are named with ID's from col A. In the target sheet I have single dates in col A (ex. from 3/01/2021 in A1 to 3/31/2021 in A31). The case numbers need to be transposed so they appear in columns next to each other but they have the same date.

I cannot use the ID's names in the code because it varies every month so I suppose that the code needs to work as some sort of comparison tool.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing?  What exactly are you having a problem with?  Do your know how to loop over your dataset?

Comment: @TimWilliams at this point I think that I would need the loop that goes through the date column row by row in raw data sheet (these dates are sorted ascending), look what ID is in column A and copy the case number into the sheet with that ID into next available cell that is next to that specific date.

Comment: That sounds like a god place to start.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've edited the post so maybe it will be better to understand what I try to achieve

Comment: How many distinct ID's (approx.), how many cases per date (approx)? Are the dates pre-populated on the worksheet or just added as they occur in the source data?

Comment: An example screenshot of an output sheet would be useful here.

Comment: Usually it's around 15-20 ID's with approximately 1500 cases per date. The dates are pre-populated in "ID" sheets. There are two links to screen shots with source data sheet and output sheet

Comment: Can you update your "output sheet" to show how it should look when completed?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kcox.jpg - should look like this

Comment: All of the dates in the data sheet exist on each "ID" sheet?

Comment: Yes, they do. On the ID sheets they are added by another subroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close: it will add the sheets if they don't already exist.

```vb
Sub Copy_to_ID_sheet()

    Dim impdate As Date, startDate As Date, daysToFillDown As Long
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim i As Long, numSheets As Long
    Dim shipment As String, m
    Dim ID As String, wsDane As Worksheet, dict As Object, ws As Worksheet
    
    startDate  = DateSerial(2021, 3, 1) 'adjust as needed
    daysToFillDown  = 31                '...and here

    Set wsDane = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dane")
    numSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    For i = 2 To wsDane.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
        impdate = wsDane.Cells(i, 10).Value
        shipment = wsDane.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ID = Sheets("Dane").Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        'already seen this ID and have a matching sheet?
        If Not dict.exists(ID) Then
            Set ws = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ID) 'does the sheet already exist?
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ws Is Nothing Then
                'no existing sheet, so add a new one
                Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add( _
                         after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(numSheets))
                numSheets = numSheets + 1
                ws.Name = ID
                'add dates to the new sheet
                With ws.Range("A1")
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" 'or whatever
                    .Value = startDate
                    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(daysToFillDown, 1)
                End With
            End If
            Set dict(ID) = ws 'save in dictionary
        Else
            Set ws = dict(ID) 'get the existing sheet
        End If
    
        'match the date to the destination sheet
        m = Application.Match(CLng(impdate), ws.Range("A1:A40"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'got a date match - add the shipment to the next available slot
            ws.Cells(m, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = shipment
        End If
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams - works better than I thought